# How to use an remote instance as "proxy" to ssh port

Tags: shell, ssh, proxy, bitbucket, port

In my local network I currently can't ssh to bitbucket:

`telnet bitbucket.org 22` fails.

But I can ssh to an remote ubuntu instance that can ssh to bitbucket (the command above works).

How can I configure my connectivity to make my traffic to bitbucket port (22) go through this intermediary instance?

I tried running the command below but did not work:

`sudo ssh -i mykey -N -L 22:remote_instance:22 ubuntu@remote_instance` (ps: remote_instance **can** access bitbucket with port 22).

Thanks :)